# iOS push notification localization not working

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to build iOS push notification server that support localization.
I add to my ios project the message string to my localization and check it using `NSLocalizedString`.

I am use this code:

```
<?PHP

if(isset($_GET['message']) && isset($_GET['sender']) ){
$deviceToken="5cca98f1 4e20c5e4 5267d4da 23437439 81959bd0 b75b7573 42a2f9d7 ceed8f0f";
$message = stripslashes($_GET['message']);
$sender = stripslashes($_GET['sender']);

$payload = '{
    "aps":{
        "alert":{
            "loc-key":"'.$message.'",
            "loc-args":["'.$sender.'"]
        },
        "badge":1,
        "sound":"bingbong.aiff"
    }
}';
print $payload;

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'password');
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
if(!$fp){
    print "Failed to connect $err $errstrn";
    return;
} else {
    print "Notifications sent!";
}

$devArray = array();
array_push($devArray,$deviceToken);

foreach($devArray as $deviceToken){
    $msg = chr(0) . pack("n",32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . pack        ("n",strlen($payload)) . $payload;
    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
}
fclose($fp);
print "This is the Device Token Sent Each Time".strlen($msg)."\n";
}
```

But no notification was sent to the device.
When I tried without localization and send the message with this payload:

```
$payload = '{
    "aps":{
        "alert":"'.$message.'",
        "badge":1,
        "sound":"bingbong.aiff"
    }
}';
```

The device received the notification.

I use [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW20) of apple.

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: it seems like you are missing `,` after the `alert`  object (before `badge`) in `aps`. Thus the json is malformed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are missing ,
fixed code:

```
$payload = '{
                "aps" : 

                    { 
                        "alert" :{
                                     "loc-key":"'.$message.'",
                                     "loc-args":["'.$sender.'"]
                                },//<=================
                          "badge" : 1,
                          "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
                    } 
            }';
```